# PHP echo into form action

Tags: php, forms, echo

Have searched around but not found an answer to this. Might be an indicator that this is a silly question, but:

I'm trying to echo some information from the page URL into a form action so that information is carried to the next page. The form and PHP looks like this:

```
<form method="link" action="surveymaker.php?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>">
```

The information that the user enters into the form gets added to the url on the next page, but not the "title" that I'm trying to add by echo. I'm fully prepared to accept that I'm going at this the totally wrong way if that's how it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You need to sanitize that value. You've left your page wide-open to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hidden input field to do this. Just add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['title']);?>">
```

Note the use of [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to sanitize the value from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea of archiving what you want ,You should use hidden inputs instead.
example place this anywhere inside your `<form>`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $_GET['title']; ?>" name="title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. worked for me..

```
<?php $title = $_GET['title'];?>
<form method="link" action="surveymaker.php?title=<?php echo $title;?>">
```